# VARCHAR type being converted incorrectly to ActiveRecord::Type::Value or ActiveRecord::Type::Decimal with mysql adapter

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

Here is what I do to end up with the wrong ActiveRecord types.

First, the schema of the table:

```
Field       | Type
------------------------------
id          | int(10) unsigned
user_name   | varchar(255)
```

Here is the code I tried in irb:

```
require 'active_record'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'mysql', host: 'mrom.akamai.com', username: 'SOME_USER', password: 'SOME_PASSWORD', database: 'mrom_v3')
c=ActiveRecord::Base.connection
r = c.exec_query("select id, user_name, 'fixed string' value from user limit 2")
t = r.column_types

=> {"id"=>#<ActiveRecord::Type::Integer:0x007fc144a5ed00 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=nil, @range=-2147483648...2147483648>, "user_name"=>#<ActiveRecord::Type::Value:0x007fc144113f20 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=nil>, "value"=>#<ActiveRecord::Type::Decimal:0x007fc144113e30 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=nil>}
```

Notice the ::Value and ::Decimal types for the user_name and value columns. I was expecting String.

How can I fix this?

Comment: don't put passwords in a SO question.  Also are you using the mysql adapter or mysql2?  mysql ruby gem hasn't been updated in 4yrs and is deprecated.

Comment: Changing to mysql2 fixed the problem. It took me a while though to figure out what version of mysql2 is compatible with my version of activerecord. Thanks.